# Coding Error about squel

Tags: mysql

When I tried to see my table after creating one using the following:

Table: students

```
CREATE TABLE students (
    studentid INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    firstname VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    lastname VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    class VARCHAR(20),
    age INT(3)
);
```

Error message was:

> Error 1064 (42000): You have an error in your sql syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your mysql server version for the right syntax to use near 'students' at line one.

Comment: This code is fine. The error must be somewhere else.

Comment: Expanding a bit on @ÁlvaroGonzález's point, you should be able to copy/paste the create table SQL above and check the results.  When these type of issues happen, it may help you to break this down to the smallest, bite-sized piece.

Comment: Many thanks about confirming the coding. Is it because i have the latest mysql.msi  8.0.12 instead of 8.0.11. Logically it doesn't make sense why it won't work on the latest version.

Comment: tested and works fine ! What DBMS are you using ? Or maybe the error is somewhere else.

Comment: It does work in my 8.0.12 server. Are you positively sure you're coping this same code and not a similar one that might even have hidden characters?

Comment: * Table: students

CREATE TABLE students (
studentid INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
firstname VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
lastname VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
class VARCHAR(20),
age INT(3)
);

Comment: @user10236102 @ÁlvaroGonzález everything looks good, but, the error code as stated in the documentations is about naming table/column as a reserved keyword, although it may be escaped using ` character.

Comment: I copied and pasted. Exactly the way it was mentioned.

Comment: Well, `students` is definitively not a [reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-S). What client software are you running the statement with?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TABLE students (
    studentid INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    firstname VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    lastname VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    class VARCHAR(20),
    age INT(3)
);
$$
```

As Alvaro said, the error is something else.  Check for non visibles characters.  Do you use MySQL Workbench?  If yes, what else is on that query page?

Comment: I am trying and to answer workbench question I am not using MYSQL workbench right now. I am very naive and really new to sql and trying to learn from Udemy started a week ago on my own. Trying figuring out what really went wrong and if there is a way to fix this. Appreciated the help.

Comment: would it help if i delete databases and create them again with tables. I am VERY NEW to sql. If this will fix my issue. Thanks everyone again.

Comment: You can try to delete and recreate your database, but I think the issue is somewhere else.

Comment: @ yes and the issue still persists :(

Comment: Which version of MySQL do you use?  What is your environnement (Windows, Linux, ..).  Are you able to do a screen capture (of your query and the error message), upload it to Google drive and share the link here.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8btd0hfckwpn659/Screenshot%202018-08-16%2016.51.35.png?dl=0

Comment: I use window 10

Comment: The create table worked in your screen shot, this is the "show table;" that doesn't works!
The command is "show tables;", with an s.

Comment: Try MySQL Workbench, this is more intuitive.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9wwpzdad6nht8uo/Screenshot%202018-08-16%2016.57.58.png?dl=0

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/j0lo7xsoe1a0vvw/Screenshot%202018-08-16%2017.02.26.png?dl=0

Comment: let me try with tableS as well . I seriously hoping that I gave me right Mysql Workbench details.

Comment: YAY!!!!!!!!!!!!!! @Daniel Blais many many thanks for TableS, suggestion I think it worked :) Here is the screen shot. I think I was able to create it. Here is the link https://www.dropbox.com/s/jerwvikth3mpnvv/Screenshot%202018-08-16%2017.14.43.png?dl=0

Comment: Many many thanks for your HELP and staying calm with me and helping. Appreciated :)